# I'm unable to post data in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, http-post

I'm having problems doing some simple stuff, I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong. I'm using the most recent versions of Ruby and Sinatra (1.9.3 and 1.3.3) under Windows

My main code is:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/form' do
  erb :form
end

post '/form' do
    "Value: '#{params[:somevalue]}'"
end
```

My ERB:

```
<form action="/form" method="post">
    <input type="text" name"somevalue">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

When I press submit, it won't show the values. It'll just show: `Value: ''`

I even tried with a plain HTML (with the same result).

These are my request headers:

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:es,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host:localhost:4567
Origin:http://localhost:4567
Referer:http://localhost:4567/form
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko)       Chrome/23.0.1271.91 Safari/537.11
```

Do I need to configure something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing a `=` after `name` in your `.erb`

Works for me after I added this.

Comment: I can't belive I didn't see that!, I guess I need to get some rest... thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

```
<form action="/form" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="somevalue">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

you have missed equal sign